# Find maximum of matrix trace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, maximum-principle

I want to solve the following:

$\max_d{\operatorname{Tr}(d^TX^TXd)}$ subject to $d^Td=1$

I would assume that I can get the maximum vector $d$ by calculating the eigenvector of $X^TX$.

Is this the right way?

Comment: I am confused. If $X$ is a square matrix and $d$ is a vector, then $d^TX^TXD$ is a number. What is the trace doing there, then?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can drop the trace since $d^TX^TXd$ is already a scalar. Without the trace, the problem you describe is the same as finding the first principal component. You want to
$$ 
\underset{d}{\text{maximize}}\quad d^TX^TXd
$$
subject to
$$
d^Td=1
$$
You can rewrite this on the Lagrangian form
$$
L(d,\lambda) = d^TX^TXd-\lambda(d^Td-1)
$$
Differentiate $L$ with respect to $d$ yields
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial d}=2(X^TX-\lambda)d=0
$$
or 
$$
X^TX d=\lambda d
$$
Thus
$$ 
d^TX^TXd = \lambda
$$
which shows that the maximum value of your problem is the largest eigenvalue, and the $d$ that achieves this value is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. So, yes you are correct in your assumption.